# I'm confused about what sentence to use

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, prepositions, adjectives

I'm a little confused about telling which of the three sentences below are correct:

1- why are you still awake in this late time?

2- why are you still awake at this late time?

3- why are you still awake until this late time?

Comment: Number two is probably most idiomatic, though "Why are you still awake this late?" would be better.

Comment: What are you doing still up?  Shouldn’t you be in bed by now?

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Jim Thanks man ,really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

"Late time" is a combination that you find in science nowadays. It is sometimes found to express what you want to say in your sentence but not as often as "late hour" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+late+hour%2Cthis+late+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20late%20hour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20late%20time%3B%2Cc0)).

- Why are you still awake at this late hour?

As mentioned by **[user John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530517/im-confused-what-expression-to-use/530518#comment1295122_530518)** in the comments, you can also do away with the adjective "late" and say "*Why are you still awake at this hour?*"; that is saying the same thing.

You can say instead "this late time of (the) day/the morning/the year" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+late+time+of+the%2Cthis+early+time+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20late%20time%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20early%20time%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthis%20late%20time%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20early%20time%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0)) (also "this early time of (the) day/the morning/the year" for the opposite).

Comment: Just plain _at this hour?_ is good enough. If it's late, it's obvious to everybody already.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, yes, that is an option… but some people choose to add "late". You can't force everyone to a such minimalist speech practices.

Comment: @JohnLawler @ LPH thank you a lot for the useful info.But do you guys think I can remove "at" as follow (Why are you still awake this hour).

Comment: @Mohamedkz In the books you find only "awwake **at** this hour":https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=awake+at+this+hour%2Cawake+this+hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cawake%20at%20this%20hour%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cawake%20at%20this%20hour%3B%2Cc0 It seems to me also that I never heard it said that way (without "at"); I wouldn't say this sentence without the preposition.